# Log4j configured with a properties file doesn´t create a file

Tags: java, logging, properties, log4j

I am new configuring log4j for a project, I have used it several times, but it´s the first time i have to configure it.

I am configuring my Log4j, I have imported the log4j-1.2.17.jar library, and I have created a properties that look like this:

```
log4j.appender.consola = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consola.threshold = INFO
log4j.appender.consola.target = System.out
log4j.appender.consola.layout = org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.consola.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{dd MMM yyyy - HH:mm:ss} [%-5p]     %c{2} - %m%n

log4j.appender.archivo = org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.archivo.file = archivo.log
log4j.appender.archivo.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.archivo.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%-5p] %c{2} - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, consola
log4j.logger.com.javatutoriales.log4j.configuracion=WARN, archivo
```

This properties file called log4j.properties is created in the default package of the project.

When I used this configuration in a class, it returns me the console log properly. I used the following code In a class:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class PruebaLog {
    /** * Logger. */ 
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PruebaLog.class); 
    public static void main (String args[]){
         logger.trace("mensaje de trace");
    logger.debug("mensaje de debug");
    logger.info("mensaje de info");
    logger.warn("mensaje de warn");
    logger.error("mensaje de error");

    }


}
```

The problem is that this class returns me the console out, but doesn´t create the file archivo.log in the path of my project.

Anybody know the reason of why it doesn´t create this log file???
Or anybody could help me with the configuration of this file in order to have a log of the diferent classes of my project in a log file???

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the file appender as you have set the console appender for the root logger:

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, consola
```

You need this instead to use the file appender:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, archivo
```

Learn more about the appenders and different log4j properties from the official document:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Comment: I have tried with both and it doesn´t work. I am also trying with:      log4j.rootLogger = TRACE, consola, archivo and nothing, the file is not created

Comment: I also tried with the configuration in the link that you suggest and nothing

Answer (score 0):

in you properties, you need to add rootLogger file

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, archivo
```

For more details you can refer to [log4j.properties config](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/)

Comment: I have tried it, and it doesn´t work. I also have tried the configuration on the site that you have posted and nothing.